# Some problem with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I don't know how can use tikpicture package to draw 2 figure below:

[image]

Please help me draw them.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe you can share your first attempt so we can suggest how to make it work

Comment: You may want to check the [policy on "how do I draw this?" questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/policy-on-how-do-i-draw-this-questions) at the meta site.

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \nn in {1,2,3,...,20}{
\node[draw,fill=red,minimum width=0.5em,minimum height=1.5em,inner sep=0] (n\nn) at ($(0.6*\nn,0)$){};
}
\node[fit=(n1) (n4),draw](input){};
\node[fit=(n5),draw](output){};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt](input.north west) -- (input.north east) node [black,midway,above=1em] {NN Input};
\draw (output.north) --++(0,10pt)node[above=1em]{NN Output};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can `{1,2,3,...,20}` be simplified?

Comment: How can create second line and three line with text header (on left corner)? How can add arrow point to box and vertical dot? Please help me more

Comment: @phuong maybe you should have some look into the very comprehensive TikZ manual.

Comment: @ Benedikt Bauer: I have read it, but i'm a newbie. I really don't know clearly about tikz. I want to learn by example.

Comment: @ all: Please help me solve this problem completely. Thank you very much